# Is there a difference between ToString("d") and ToShortDateString()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have been recently performing code reviews on quite a large system which has users around the world.

I noticed that some developers are displaying dates using the following code:

```
userDOB.ToString("d")
```

and others are using this:

```
userDOB.ToShortDateString()
```

Is there any difference between what these 2 lines should output? 
If not then i am going to push for having some consistency and using one of these formats, personally i prefer ToShortDateString() as it is more readable (unless someone has a better reason to use ToString("d")).

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx) _The return value is **identical** to the value returned by specifying the "d" standard DateTime format string with the ToString(String) method._

Comment: Please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It seems there is no difference at all. The output of both will depend upon the DatTime setting in Control Panel. On my PC, the Date Setting was in the format of M/dd/yyyy. Hence both output using the ToShortDateString() and ToString("d"), are the same.

Answer (score 4):

If you see both methods

```
  public string ToShortDateString()
        {
            return DateTimeFormat.Format(this, "d", DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
        }
```

and

```
  public string ToString(string format)
        {
            return DateTimeFormat.Format(this, format, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
        }
```

you can see the difference for your self that in `ToString` you have to define format in your case `"d"` and in `ToShortDateString` the format is predefined but they both are pointing to the same method `DateTimeFormat.Format`